# Get URL for a date_query results in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this line of code:

```
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'     => 'January 1st, 2015',
            'before'    => 'February 15th, 2015',
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This code will return all the post published between Jan 1st and Feb 15th. 
My question is can I somehow create a link to the results of this query?

For example I can go to

```
localhost/wordpress?monthnum=1
```

and get all posts from January, but is there a link, or can I create custom link that will accept the parameters of my date_query, so I can display all the posts that match my query?

Basically I just want to show all posts published between specific dates on a separate page, and I want a link to that page, but I don't know if such thing is possible.

Answer (score 0):

What about try Query string ?!
for example :

```
  localhost/wordpress?monthnum=1
```

will pass $_GET variable to the current page , so you can get the value :

```
  $month=$_GET['monthnum'];
```

Then you can parse this value to a specific month for example:
       $StringDate='the default date';
       if($month==1) $StringDate='January 1st, 2015';
Finally pass this value to your Query :

```
        $args = array(
        'date_query' => array(
        array(
        'after'     => $StringDate,
        'before'    => 'February 15th, 2015',
        'inclusive' => true,
        ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```